# Neo4j count Query

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher

```
match(m:master_node:Application)-[r]-(k:master_node:Server)-[r1]-(n:master_node) 
where (m.name contains '' and (n:master_node:DeploymentUnit or n:master_node:Schema)) 
return distinct m.name,n.name
```

Hi,I am trying to get total number of records for the above query.How I change the query using count function to get the record count directly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query uses the [aggregating funtion](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT`. Distinct pairs of `m.name, n.name` values are used as the "grouping keys".

```
MATCH (m:master_node:Application)--(:master_node:Server)--(n:master_node) 
WHERE EXISTS(m.name) AND (n:DeploymentUnit OR n:Schema)
RETURN m.name, n.name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
```

I assume that `m.name contains ''` in your query was an attempt to test for the existence of `m.name`. This query uses the `EXISTS()` function to test that more efficiently.

[UPDATE]

To determine the number of distinct `n` and `m` pairs in the DB (instead of the number of times each pair appears in the DB):

```
MATCH (m:master_node:Application)--(:master_node:Server)--(n:master_node) 
WHERE EXISTS(m.name) AND (n:DeploymentUnit OR n:Schema)
WITH DISTINCT m.name AS n1, n.name AS n2
RETURN COUNT(*) AS cnt
```

Some things to consider for speeding up the query even further:

1. Remove unnecessary label tests from the `MATCH` pattern. For example, can we omit the `master_node` label test from any nodes? In fact, can we omit all label testing for any nodes without affecting the validity of the result? (You will likely need a label on at least one node, though, to avoid scanning all nodes when kicking off the query.)
2. Can you add a direction to each relationship (to avoid having to traverse relationships in both directions)?
3. Specify the relationship types in the `MATCH` pattern. This will filter out unwanted paths earlier. Once you do so, you may also be able to remove some node labels from the pattern as long as you can still get the same result.
4. Use the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) clause to evaluate the number of DB hits needed by different Cypher queries.

Comment: Hi @cyberssm thanks for the response... basically I just need the count number...I use this count number in my application to do some pagination...my query count is somewhere around 200k but it's causing some performance issues..it's taking so much time to get the records.

Comment: What are you counting?

Comment: Total number of records that query retrieves

Comment: Since the count is different for each pair of names, don't you also need the pair of names? What are you trying to sow on each "page"?

Comment: Yeah...I don't need the pair of names...I just need the number of records..

Comment: But then you'd get N different numbers without information about what each number means. Or are you trying to get the total of all N numbers?

Comment: That's ok...but the thing is how fast it would be...

Comment: SQL has the capability to get the records of another query like..select count(*) from ( select distinct n,m from table);. Can't we do something similar in cypher

Comment: There are many potential ways to speed things up. For example, is it really necessary to always test for the `master_node` label in addition to the other labels? Can you add a direction to each relationship (to avoid looking in both directions)? Can you specify the type of each relationship (to avoid traversing relationships with the wrong types), and if so, would you get the same results if you removed some node labels from the `MATCH` pattern?

Comment: Have tried all the scenarios u mentioned above but no luck.

Comment: The SQL statement `select count(*) from ( select distinct n,m from table);` shows the number of distinct `n/m` pairs. Is *that* what you want? There many things that we can count.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want with cypher

Comment: Ok..tried with your edited answer it gives me the exact count but still its taking too much time...Just give u an idea the output of my query is 173254.

Comment: match (app:Application)-->(d:Server)-->(du) where ((du:DeploymentUnit or du:Schema)) with distinct app.name as n1,du.name as n2 return count(*) as cnt;

Comment: I have inserted a new #3 to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of how to use count in the Neo4j docs [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-count)

In your case the first example where:

```
count(*)
```

Is used to return a count of each returned item should work.